# Can you override the automatically captured value of a parameter attributed with CallerMemberName by explicitly passing a value?

Tags: c#, attributes, .net-4.5

I have a situation where in some context I want to pass an explicit value to my method with a parameter marked up with CallerMemberName, and from other contexts I want it to automatically capture.
I want to know if this is possible, or will the attribute always take priority?

Why would I want to do that, you ask.
I am writing an auditing component that can be called from anywhere. It takes some parameters required for the auditing context, as well as the CallerMemberName param.
But on some of my super classes I already have certain bits of information relevant to the auditing, so I wrote a method there that only takes the CallerMemberName param. It then calls through to my auditing component passing the parameters it already has in it's context as well as the caller member name it already implicitly captured.

Comment: Why do you ask questions and immediately answer them yourself?

Comment: @TyCobb nothing wrong, and that is even encouraged. But I'm not sure if it's a great question.

Comment: @TyCobb, see [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: This question helped me. Sure I could have thrown together a quick unit test and seen if it worked but being able to google it was _so_ much more helpful and expedient. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

Yes, it is possible, so it can be used both implicitly and explicitly.

```
private void CaptureCaller(
     [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = "")
{
    // callerMemberName will contain the name of the method that called CaptureCaller if called with no parameters.
    // callerMemberName will contain the value of the passed in parameter if provided.
}

CaptureCaller();
CaptureCaller("custom value");
```

Comment: Could you post the code solution to this so it helps people who come across this in the future?

Comment: @SergueiFedorov, there's not a whole lot of code involved.  The question is whether or not an explicitly passed in argument to a method whose parameter is marked with `[CallerMemberName]` will still respect that value or will instead always use the implicit value indicated by the caller of the method.

Comment: Agree with @KirkWoll, but added a bit of code to try make things clearer. :)

Comment: Note that Resharper will show warning "Explicit argument passed to parameter with caller info attribute"

Comment: What if I explicitly send default value as parameter? Will it use my value or grab the CallerMemberName? For example in the above example, what happens when `CaptureCaller("");` is called?

Comment: For clarification, I just tested - and the passed value will be used even if it's the default value. So in the example of `CaptureCaller("");`, the value will be `""` (empty string, which is also the default value)